# Foursquare API Access without registered application

Tags: foursquare

I have just an idea for now to develop an application based on foursquare API.

I checked in the website that a creation of an application inside the foursquare is needed to access the api functions.

There some form fields in the application creation that cannot be filled by me as I don't have an application yet, like web address home page, privacy police page, etc.

I want to perform some tests for a certain time and then choose if I'll proceed with the application development or not.

For now I just need access for the venue stats function. Do you know if it's possible to have access to this function without have an official application?

Regards,

Rodrigo Lima

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an application in order to [get an OAuth token](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth), which you need to call venues/stats. In practice, during testing, the only real field that needs to be accurate is the redirect URI, which you'll need for OAuth. The others can take dummy values for now, so long as you go and change them before you publish.